# Silverlight dataGrid binding with ria Service doesn' work

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, wcf-ria-services

i'm new to Silverlight and it's totally driving me crazy!

i'm using SL4 and trying to bind datagrid with a Domain Service Query:

what i did exactly is i generate an ado.net entity model from my database,
then create a domain Service class from this model.

then in my page i put Datagrid & button.

in the click event for this button i write this code:

```
RRDomainContext rr = new RRDomainContext();
this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = rr.Rooms;
this.rr.Load(this.rr.GetRoomsQuery());
```

when this method executed the nothing changed at the datagrid.

can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is async only, so if the query is a large one it can either take a long time to return, or if it's a large query that goes over the 64k limit it can fail and you don't know about it.

As a thought, if you're using RIA services to bind to something reasonably simple, use the "Data Source" for the entity, it's a lot less likely to give issues.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsdata/the-data-source-window-support-in-wcf-ria-services)

Comment: the data is very small it's less than 5 records
and i don't wanna to use data source thing because i wanna to deal with the object directly